# cut the spectrogram of a wav file

Tags: python-3.x, image, wav, spectrogram

I want to horizontally cut the spectrogram of a wav file into 24 pieces,and after measuring the power of each piece, and finally rank the pieces by power orders what should I do please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show some code that you have written to try out the same? It would be easier to help if we have something to build upon and rectify issues, if any.

Additionally please try basic image manipulation to do the same. Instead of cutting you could divide the image into N (here 24) regions and analyze them in parallel using multiprocessing.

Comment: thanks
this is exactly what i want to do, i want to grab the spectrogram as an image and split this image horizontally into 24 pieces if you can help me.

Comment: could you let me know if the size of the image is some fixed dimension? Or is it going to vary? Also could you share the piece of code that you are using to calculate the power of a piece?

Comment: I am working on a lot of image, the height of the image is fixed but the length is variable

Comment: Could you send the code which you're using to compute the power of a W x H size image?

Comment: import cv2
from pywt import dwt2
import pywt
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread("/home/raviraj/PycharmProjects/Diabetic/SYMPTOMS/1369_right.jpeg")
im = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, (cH, cV, cD) = dwt2(im.T, 'db1')
# a - LL, h - LH, v - HL, d - HH as in matlab
Energy = (cH**2 + cV**2 + cD**2).sum()/im.size

print(Energy)